# Issue lazy loading module with NgMoudleFactoryLoader Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a popups module that I wanted to lazy load outside of the regular router lazy-loading so I have done the following

**angular.json**

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ...
    "options": {
      ...
      "lazyModules": ["src/popup-components/popups.module"],
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Added the module to the lazyModules in the angular.json so angular knows to bundle it seperately

**popups.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export default class PopupModule {}
```

**app.component**

```js
@ViewChild('entry', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) entry: ViewContainerRef

...

constructor(
  private _loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
  private _injector: Injector
) { } 

...

// takes the popup compenent to render as an argument
loadModule(popupComponent) {
  this._loader.load('src/popup-components/popups.module').then(moduleFactory => {
  const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this._injector).instance;
  const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(popupComponent);
  this.entry.createComponent(compFactory);
});
}
```

now when I run `ng serve` all this works as expected, no errors or anything... but when I run `ng build --prod` I get the following errors

> ERROR in ./src/popup-components/popups.module.ngfactory.js 58:64-79
>   "export 'PopupsModule' (imported as 'i1') was not found in './popups.module'
>   ERROR in ./src/popup-components/popups.module.ngfactory.js 58:8885-8900
>   "export 'PopupsModule' (imported as 'i1') was not found in './popups.module'
>   ERROR in ./src/popup-components/popups.module.ngfactory.js 58:8902-8917
>   "export 'PopupsModule' (imported as 'i1') was not found in './popups.module'

Now if you noticed above in the `popups.module` I am using `export default class` instead of the regular `export default` If I remove `default` my app builds fine running `ng build --prod` but the dynamic loading of the module no longer works I get this error when I try and run the `loadModule()` method

> console.js:35 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in 'src/popup-components/popups.module'

I'm not sure what to do from here I cant find any resources of a similar issue

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was actually able to solve this issue heres what I did:

In my `loadModule()` function in the `.load()` section I needed to do the following

```js
this._loader.load('src/popup-components/popups.module#PopupsModule)
```

so this looks similar to the old (pre Angular 8) way of lazy loading routing components so the `#` is used to denote where our file path ends and to tell the load function the name of the `PopupsModule`

then I also had to change

```
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this._injector).instance;
```

to

```
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this._injector);
```

and now the project builds fine using `ng build --prod`